# Django - Pass data from javascript to view & redirect to a new url

Tags: javascript, django, view

On my webpage there are 2 buttons - A & B. I want to capture the button clicked by the user in front end & send it back to the server so that I can generate the appropriate token for the user. Then redirect the user to the right url - "/A" or "/B" depending on what they clicked.

urls.py

```
    path('buttonTest/', buttonView), # Initially testing with one url
```

Views.py

```
def buttonView(requests):
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        clicked_button_val = requests.POST.get('clicked_button')
        # generate auth token
        render(requests, 'test.html')
```

test.html

```
<form id="testform">
    <button name="subject" id="A" type="submit" value="A">A</button>
    <button name="subject" id="B" type="submit" value="B">B</button>
</form>
<script>
$("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            "clicked_button": $(this).val(),
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I am able to successfully pass the data from front-end to views. But the url doesn't redirect to  /buttonTest. If I add redirect in html like this,

```
<button name="subject" id="A" type="submit" value="A" onclick="location.href='/buttonTest'">A</button>
```

then the request in views.py becomes a GET request & is not able to access what the user clicked.

What I want to do is capture the button clicked by user via a POST request & then redirect the user to a new url & pass the data captured in the POST request to the new url & view.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your ajax request is not even used, because your buttons have `type="submit"` and you never prevent the form submission. The simplest method would be to set a different `name` attribute on both the buttons and forego using JavaScript:

```
<form id="testform">
    <button name="submit_A" id="A" type="submit" value="A">A</button>
    <button name="submit_B" id="B" type="submit" value="B">B</button>
</form>
```

Now in the view:

```
def buttonView(request): # request should be singular(naming convention)!!
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'submit_A' in requests.POST:
            # generate auth token for button A and redirect
        elif 'submit_B' in requests.POST:
            # generate auth token for button B and redirect
        render(requests, 'test.html')
```

Comment: The question is how do I redirect with the data to a new url? 

Again, this was a simplified example. I have more than 2 buttons.

Comment: @Piyush **redirect** with the data? You don't redirect with data. If you need to do that then you should be posting to the other urls instead of redirecting to it (assuming you have anything other than the submit buttons in the form). Please clarify what exactly do you want.

Comment: Here's what I want - Get form data from client to server & then redirect user to new url with the collected data

Comment: @Piyush check Iain Shelvington's answer. As both of us said you don't redirect with data. His answer appears to be most suitable for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include data in a redirect since a redirect triggers a GET request.

You can however add a [`formaction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit#formaction) attribute to submit inputs to submit the same form to different URLs

```
<input type="submit" formaction="/handle-a/" value="A">
<input type="submit" formaction="/handle-b/" value="B">
```